# How do we forgive ourselves?

Tags: personal-practice

When we make a mistake, how do we forgive ourselves? I know that bhikkhus must confess in front of the Sangha if they break a certain Vinaya (monastic rule). But what about lay people? Do we have to do some kind of confession in front of other people too?

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate of existing questions. Please check and see if the answers to the linked questions answer your question too. If you feel that your question is different from the linked questions or if you want to change your question such that it will be different, please write to me in the comments.

Comment: Thank you, I will delete this question

Comment: **Dhamma sukha** (i edited it) buddhism on youtube has good self-forgiveness and forgiveness meditations

Comment: @Dhamma sukha Thank you!

Comment: @ruben2020, it seems like I can't delete this question, sorry (the 'delete question' button won't budge when I clicked on it)

Comment: It's ok. We can just leave it closed.